# TabBar Controller Screen Black When I add the .h and .m

Tags: xcode, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

Still new with Xcode I would like to add a tabBar Controller after a viewController.

In the storyboard i added a tabBarController after the viewController

I performed the segue from my view controller to the tabBar Controller with :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"succesfulConnection" sender:self];
```

Ok it works, i can also add some viewController to get 4 tabs. Then i created 4 different .h and .m (UITabBarController subclass) and assign each of them with the good viewController. 
But when i run the app in the simulator i get a full black screen for all of them...

Impossible to display a label or other thing ...

What did i make wrong ?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the reason for the black screen is that the four view controllers you present in the `UITabBarController` are plain `UIViewController`s (as they normally should be) and *not* subclasses of `UITabBarController`.

Make those view controllers subclasses of `UIViewController` and see if it helps.

*(For a more detailed explanation see the comments below.)*

Comment: Thanks !!! Im so stupid shah!

But i dont understand why i shouldn't use a subclass of UITabBarController ? 
Is there an explication to that ?

Comment: Read about UITabBarController in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes, there is. The reason lies in the fundamentals of object oriented programming. So if you want to understand that I suggest you read a book or a good tutorial on that topic. In short: If something (A) is a subclass of something else (B) then an object of class A is of class B as well. Example: If you have a class Fruit and a class Apple then a particular apple is not only of class Apple but of class Fruit as well. In other words: The class Apple *inherits* from the class Fruit.

Comment: If your four view controllers presented in the different tabs would inherit from `UITabBarController` i.e. if they were instances of a *subclass* of `UITabBarController` then they would be tab bar controllers themselves. This would mean that you have two tab bars - one on top of the other. But as you only dragged a normal `UIViewController` to your storyboard you cannot mark them as `UITabBarControllers`.

Comment: Another (maybe better) example just came across my mind: Let's look at a family with parents and 4 children. The parents and all 4 children are "instances" of the class *Human*. (Just as the tab bar controller *and* the 4 view controllers presented in the tabs are instances of the class *UIViewController*.) Whereas the children are *not* instances of the class *Parent* (at least as long as they are all of young age and haven't reproduced yet ;)). Of course there is a relation between the parents and the children but as the name suggests it's a parent-child-relation, *not* subclassing.

Comment: Thanks Mischa for all that ! It s totally clearer right now :)